# Iterating with lambda and map python

Tags: python, lambda

Here is my code:

```
map(lambda i: 3*i, map(lambda x: x, [[1, 2],[3, 4]]))
```

It outputs: `[[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2], [3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4]]`

How do I modify it to print `3, 6, 9, 12`?

I do not want to use append. Just map and lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you observe arises from the fact that the inner `map` returns a sequence of lists, not a sequence of numbers. This is because that `map` is iterating over a list containing smaller lists. So, if you use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` to flatten that list, you'll get a sequence of numbers. You can then use the outer `map` to triplicate them

```
In [67]: L = [[1, 2],[3, 4]]

In [68]: for i in map(lambda i: 3*i, itertools.chain.from_iterable(L)): print(i)
3
6
9
12
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code didn't work as expected because in Python the `*` operator is polymorphic. Thus if `x` and `n` are numbers, `x*n` returns the product of both numbers, but if one of the operands (say `n`) is an integer and the other is a sequence (.e. `x` is a list, a tuple or a string) the expression `x*n` returns the sequence which results of concatenating `x` with itself `n` times. Examples:

```
>>> .1 * 2.5
0.25
>>> [1, 2] * 3
[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
>>> "beep" * 2
beepbeep
```

In order to get the expected result you need to flatten out your list before applying `map()`:

```
>>> your_list = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> flat_list = [item for sublist in your_list for item in sublist]
>>> flat_list
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> triples = map(lambda x: 3*x, flat_list)
>>> triples
[3, 6, 9, 12]
```

Actually you don't need to use `map()` and `lambda`. I think using a one-liner list comprehension would be more pythonic:

```
>>> triples = [3*item for sublist in your_list for item in sublist]
>>> triples
[3, 6, 9, 12]
```